# karaf console is not starting in opendaylight startup archetype

Tags: java, maven, apache-karaf, karaf, opendaylight

I'm following [this post](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html) to create a sample hello world rpc on opendaylight.

I created and built the project using opendaylight-startup-archetype successfully. But post that when I'm trying to start the karaf console from the built project it is stuck at the following screen.

[image]

I also monitored karaf logs and this is error I can see.

[image]

PS: This is the command I used to start the karaf console.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Archetype is broken right now on the bleeding edge current latest master branch.  Watch https://jira.opendaylight.org/browse/ARCH-3 to get notified when we'll have fixed it.  You may be able to use previous versions.